# Как изменять слой игрока в зависимости от положения других игроков? Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

У меня есть игра где перемещаются люди, мне нужно чтобы елси например игрок находится пониже другого игрока но на нем так скажем, то он был впереди, тоесть менять слой, а если он выше, то он ниже слоем, тоесть чтоб он не перекрывал другого игрока
Объясните пожалуйста, как это можно сделать? У меня есть вариант сделать линию для каждого игрока, которая проходит по середине экрана, с левой середины экрана до правой, как горизонт и тут уже прописать условия и менять слои, но я не очень представляю, как это сделать
и еще вопрос, как в коде меня Order In Layer для объекта?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так, изменить Order in Layer:

```
public GameObject object
object.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sortingOrder = 1;
```